# Elasticsearch AND Parens

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm attempting to do the following with the query dsl but I'll express it as SQL:

```
(matrices.matrix = 'Matrix1' AND matrices.count = 1) AND (matrices.matrix = 'Matrix2' AND matrices.count >= 0)
```

So, I need to get docs that have both of these nested docs with these values.

This is the nested document it sits on the _source level

```
"matrices": [
              {
                 "terms": [],
                 "count": 0,
                 "matrix": "none"
              },
              {
                 "terms": [
                    "greater"
                 ],
                 "count": 1,
                 "matrix": "Matrix1"
              }
           ]
```

And here is the mapping for the sub-doc:

```
"matrices": {
              "type": "nested",
              "include_in_parent": true,
              "properties": {
                 "count": {
                    "type": "long"
                 },
                 "matrix": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "terms": {
                    "type": "string"
                 }
              }
           }
```

So, I need to generate a query that will allow me to get docs that match both (matrix = 'none' && count=0) && (matrix = 'Matrix' && count = 1)

Thanks,

Comment: Can you also show your document mapping type and one or two sample documents?

Comment: updated with requested info

Answer (score -1):

So basically you want to retrieve documents that MUST contain two nested documents with the following criteria:

1. one nested document with `matrices.count=0` AND `matrices.matrix=none`
2. another nested document with `matrices.count=1` AND `matrices.matrix=Matrix`

Then with the mapping you have, you can achieve that result using the following query. We use `bool/must` for two `nested` queries which in turn match the criteria each of the nested documents that must be retrieved.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "matrices",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "matrices.count": 0
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "matrices.matrix": "none"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "matrices",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "matrices.count": 1
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "matrices.matrix": "matrix"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```